# Ceiling Decimal in apex

Tags: apex, math, rounding

I want to get the nearest ceiling for the decimal value.

```
For 1268.0 => I want to get 1300.
For 2537.0 => I want to get 2500.
```

It would be like Excel function.

I used value.round(roundingMode.UP) to get the nearest whole value. But still I can't achieve what I want.

Any input will be so helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could divide by 100, do the rounding and then multiply again by 100.
Not really a salesforce issue.

Comment: I agree, and this seems like a most reasonable technical solution.